# How to generate a dynamic number of samples from tensorflow dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

My goal is to allow my Tensorflow Dataset pipeline to allow near arbitrary sized inputs, which will be converted to uniform (known at 'compile' time) sized samples, which number more than the original. Thus I have a py_func (similar to [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47337031/how-to-expand-tf-data-dataset-with-additional-example-transformations-in-tensorf) in idea of mapping one to many) which aims to return a dataset for use in flat_map

```
def split_fn(x, y):
    """ Splits X into a number of subsamples, each labeled y"""
    full_width = x.shape[1]
    full_height = x.shape[0]
    print(full_width)
    print(full_height)

    slice_width = SLICE_WIDTH
    slice_height = SLICE_HEIGHT

    # The splits created by these offset cover the complete input image
    offsets1 = [[x,0] for x in range(0, full_width-slice_width, slice_width)]
    if full_width % slice_width != 0:
        offsets1.append([full_width-slice_width, 0])

    # The splits from these offsets are random, intended for data augmentation
    offsets2 = [[x,0] for x in random.sample(range(0,full_width-slice_width), 5)]

    #Combine the two lists of offsets
    offsets = offsets1 + offsets2


    image = x.reshape(1, full_height, full_width, 1)

    #This creates a list of the slices corresponding to the offsets
    ts = list(map(lambda offset: tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(image,
                                                               offset[1],
                                                               offset[0],
                                                               slice_height,
                                                               slice_width),
                  offsets))
    #Create and concatenate a dataset for each of the samples
    datasets = map(lambda d: tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors((d, y)), ts)
    ds = reduce((lambda x, y: x.concatenate(y)), datasets)
    return ds
```

However, where I define offsets1,

> TypeError: __index__ returned non-int (type NoneType)

. I've tried to fix this by wrapping it in a py_func which returns a dataset

```
dataset = dataset.flat_map(
lambda image, label:  tuple(tf.py_func(
split_fn, [image, label], [tf.data.Dataset])))
```

however I can't seem to get this to correctly work:

> TypeError: Expected DataType for argument 'Tout' not <  class
>   'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.Dataset' > .

What can I do to get this to work?

Thank you

Comment: At what line is this error?

Comment: When not wrapped in py_func, the error occurs  at   
    offsets1 = [[x,0] for x in range(0, full_width-slice_width, slice_width)] 
and when it is wrapped, the error occurs at the call 
    dataset = dataset.flat_map(
    lambda image, label:  tuple(tf.py_func(
    split_fn, [image, label], [tf.data.Dataset])))